# Server Print RTF Files

Tags: c#, .net, windows, rtf

How can i print a rtf file from a window service application without any user dialogs?

I have found ways to txt files but not RTF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some possible ways :

1) Use Word Automation

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10999/Printing-Word-Documents-in-C#%3a%20Print%20rtf

2)  Load the rtf file in a richtextbox (on a winform app) .. and then print the contents as shown here

[How to print the content of a RichTextBox control by using Visual C# .NET or Visual C# 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;812425)

3) Also try this example..dunno if it works with rtf.. but it should

http://geekswithblogs.net/bleepzter/archive/2008/10/09/printing-a-pdf-file-to-a-network-printer-with-c.aspx

4) You can also save the content of richtextbox control as image and print it..

http://stpetrus27.wordpress.com/2011/08/24/c-rtf-to-image/